# Laravel - Add custom column in select with Eloquent query buider

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

this is a simplified use case, only to illustrate what I want to achieve:

Considering this query in pure SQL:

```
SELECT url, 1 AS active
FROM  `modules` 
WHERE 1
```

How can I add the constant active column using query builder ?

Here is my Query Builder without the extra column:

```
DB::table('modules')
->get(['url']);
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Simplest would be to use DB::raw

```
     DB::table('modules')->get(['url', DB::raw('1 as active')]);
```

Comment: Please, anyway to do it with eloquent without using DB::raw()?

Answer (score 21):

We can add subquery or "custom column" in select with first argument of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectSub` method as `raw SQL` or `Closure`, or `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`. Better solution is **closure** or `Builder`. 
In your case it will be:

```
$modules = DB::table('modules')->select('url')
    ->selectSub(function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('1');
    }, 'active')
    ->get();
```

Tested on `Laravel 5.5`. In closure `$query` is a object of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` for subquery. Prepared SQL will be:

```
select `url`, (select 1) as `active` from `modules`
```

Extended example... If we use `App\Module` eloquent for modules and we need get `url` of modules and `count` of their submodules with `id > 5`, we can write next:

```
$modules = App\Module::select('url')
    ->selectSub(function ($query) {

        /** @var $query \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder */
        $query->from('submodules')
              ->selectRaw('COUNT(*)')
              ->where('id', '>', 5)
              ->whereRaw('`modules`.`id` = `submodules`.`module_id`');

    }, 'countOfSubModules')
    ->get();
```

Prepared SQL will be:

```
select `url`, 
   (select COUNT(*) from `submodules`
       where `id` > ? and `modules`.`id` = `submodules`.`module_id`)
   as `countOfSubModules` 
from `modules`
```

Or you can write your example with **raw sql**:

```
$sql = 'SELECT 1';
$modules = DB::table('modules')->select('url')->selectSub($sql, 'active')->get();
```

Then prepared SQL will be:

```
select `id`, (SELECT 1) as `active` from `modules`
```

---

**For get all columns** necessarily to use `select('*')`:

```
App\Module::select('*')->selectSub($sql, 'text')->get();
```

**Not**:

```
App\Module::selectSub($sql, 'text')->get();
```

Comment: Consider explaining a little better what you have done.

Comment: I apologize if you are talking about the date of the post. I did not see it at once. I think the solution might be useful. Or do I have a mistake?

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is not useful.. I'm just saying it can be even more useful  if you explain what you have done.

Comment: I changed the description with adding details and maybe rewrite it later. Thanks! Sorry for my English. :)

Comment: Very nice! I think we both agree it is much better now. Users can now actually learn something from your answer. I will upvote your answer for your effort. Keep it up, good job! :) Peace

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution if you are using eloquent

```
$people = Modules::select([
            DB::raw("(SELECT 'CUSTOM_FIELD') as custom_field")
        ])
        ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel Eloquent has very flexible query builder.

You can specify a column to return as:

```
$users = DB::table('modules')->select('1 as active')->get(['url']);
```

Comment: I think the solution is close to that, but I get this SQL error when trying your solution: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'field list' (SQL: select `1` as `active` from `modules`)

Comment: This will ignore `['url']`.

Comment: This is not working. I get the same error as ZarkDev. `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1'  in 'field list'`